# Persistance's CriteriaBuilder - check if greater than 0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria

I gave up trying to figure it out so I ask here :) my goal is to filter some data in database query by CriteriaBuilder. Each `Client` has fields like `howMuchOrders` and `orderTotalValue`.

Here I try to check if my given `atLeastAverageValue` is lower than `averageTotalValueExpression`(calculated by dividing `orderTotalValue` by `howMuchOrders`). At very begining I need to check if my `atLeastAverageValue` is not null. Otherwise I do not want to add predicate to list of executed predicates with query.

Everything works fine until `root.get("orderCount")` gives zero (which is possible) and it throws `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`. I could catch and handle this exception, but it is not the way i like to do it. Firstly I'd like to check if value in `root.get("orderCount")` is not null. If it is not - calculate and add prediacte to predicates list. Otherwise do nothing.

```
private void addMaxAveragePredicate(BigDecimal atLeastAverageValue, List<Predicate> predicates, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<?> root) {
    if (atLeastAverageValue!=null) {
            Expression averageTotalValueExpression = builder.quot(root.get("orderCount"), root.get("orderTotalValue")).as(BigDecimal.class);
            predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(averageTotalValueExpression, atLeastAverageValue));

    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution! I was not able to find out if the value is greater than 0 like in `if` statement, but I imagined how would the sql query look. I just needed to check if `orderCount > 0` and `orderValue/order` in logical `AND` :) looks like this:

```
predicates.add(builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get("orderCount"), 0), 
builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(exQuot, attValue)));
```

I just needed some time :)